# Stellar mass of galaxies

Tags: mass, luminosity

Given the magnitudes (in the i-band) of certain galaxies, I would like to calculate their **stellar mass (in terms of solar masses)**. So far, I have calculated their absolute magnitudes and gotten to working out the mass-light ratio $M/L$ for each galaxy.

e.g. $M/L=0.563$

Values I have are the calculated $M/L$ for each galaxy, and the $i$-band apparent ($13.25$) and absolute ($-18.06$) magnitudes for the galaxy, as well as the distance ($18.44Mpc$).

From this I need to get the mass of the galaxy $M$ in terms of solar masses. Therefore I assume I first need to calculate the i-band luminosity for the galaxy in solar masses $L_i$. This is where I am stuck.

However, once I have $L_i$  next step would be ...
$$M_g = 0.563 * L_i$$

Ultimately, given these values, how would I go about estimating the stellar mass of a galaxy in terms of solar masses?

Comment: Have you already seen http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March05/Read/Read_contents.html ?

Comment: @AlexanderJanssen, thanks for that. Unfortunately it doesn't help me too much as that's applied to specific galaxy types, whereas I need it more generically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation between [absolute magnitude](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_magnitude) $M$ and luminosity $L$ for stars
$$\frac{L_{Star}}{L_{Sun}}=10^{(M_{Sun}-M_{Star})/2.5}$$
should also be appliable to i-band luminosities of galaxies.

[Taking the absolute magnitude 4.08 of the sun on the I-band](http://www.ucolick.org/~cnaw/sun.html) the luminosity of a galaxy with absolute magnitude −18.06 would be
$$\frac{L_{Galaxy}}{L_{Sun}}=10^{(4.08−(-18.06))/2.5}=0.7178\cdot 10^9.$$
An order of magnitude estimate for the mass of the galaxy would be
$0.563\cdot 0.7178\cdot 10^9=0.404\cdot 10^9$ solar masses.

But $M/L$ isn't necessarily biased the same way for the sun to $M_i/L_i$ as for the galaxy.
Therefore you'll probably need to compare the spectrum of the sun with the spectrum of the galaxy to find out the ratios of the i-band fraction of the total emission. Absorption and extinction at different wavelength may be different, therefore determining kind of mean temperature of stars in the galaxy could help finding a more realistic estimate for the stellar mass.

A similiar approach has been used in [this paper](http://www.ifa.hawaii.edu/reu/2007research/whiting.pdf).

Comment: thanks for that. That equation makes sense however $M_i$ is an unknown that I need to solve for, ye it's in both sides of the equation.

Comment: I guess you could just integrate over a reasonable range, better if tuned for your given galaxy.

Comment: @AfroBoy On the right side of the equation you have the (probably known) $M_i/L_i$ mass-luminosity ratios. Might it be you confused $M_i$ with $M_*$ in this case?

Comment: @Gerald Thanks again for your help. I think I'm getting confused in abstracts, so I've reworded the question with some more concrete details.

Comment: @AfroBoy Thanks for the details! I'll try to solve it. The formula first given is applicable to main sequence stars, not necessarily to galaxies.

Comment: @Gerald Thank you so much. That makes total sense now. I understand M/L is only really for main sequence stars, but I have other corrections I can apply along the way to get a better estimate. Thank you!

Comment: @AfroBoy Welcome! Glad to have been able to help you, at the end.

Answer (score 0):

To estimate galaxy stellar mass with broadband photometry, you want to compare your observations to the [spectral energy distribution](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/March10/Walcher/Walcher6.html) (SED) of the galaxy. There are synthetic SED libraries which will generate SEDs for different types of galaxies with different masses.

[image: An example galaxy SED]

For each template you can figure out the expected luminosity in the I-band and find the best match. For this method, it's really best to have more than one point for comparison. Since the near IR will likely be a blackbody from your evolved stellar population, you might want to see if you can supplement your I-band data with [2MASS](http://irsa.ipac.caltech.edu/applications/2MASS/PubGalPS/) observations.